# Need to dynamically alter the main timeline display dimension to match a loaded 3D swf's dimension to keep source 3D properties?

Tags: actionscript-3

The issue I'm having is that I have a main "wrapper" 100x100 (but it could be any size) - it's just there to hold and display whatever content, swf, gif, etc we may want to throw into it. As long as the loaded content doesn't have 3D animation like rotationY going on, it displays fine. But when it does, the 3D "anchor" properties (like projectionCenter) of the loaded swf inherit those of the main timeline (i.e. 100x100 (main) vs 728x90 (loaded)). If I change the dimension of the main "wrapper" in Flash IDE to match what's coming in - the 3D behaves fine, but I won't know what the dimensions of the content will be until it comes, so I need a way (if there is one) to dynamically alter the main "wrapper" or root display object through AS. Stuff like "this.width = loader.width" or "stage.width = loader.width" or "root.width = loader.width" etc doesn't work. Flex has the hBox and vBox - does AS have anything?

Comment: Having the same problem here.  Before I stop here, I try a lot of things you tried and more. Change the projectionCenter of the loaded movie, of the wrapper, assign stage size for both, set NO_SCALE for both, nothing does it, the perspective is not the same as if I didn't have the wrapper.

Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use ExternalInterface to call a javascript function in the wrapper html, this will change the dimensions of the height/width of the enclosing div that wraps your .swf embd (Embed at width="100%" and height="100%") alternatively use swfobject to get a handle on the embedded object and change the height/width properties to match.

Then you can attach a Event.RESIZE listener and reposition your elements when the swf has been resized to fit the contents.

This is an example (Though just the height of the swf is changing) http://www.markgriffo.com/scrollTest/

Comment: Thanks, Chris, but the wrapper is a compiled flash swf, not a div., I'm already embeding it at the incoming content's size, but I still need to change the main timeline dimensions of that "primary"/wrapper swf to match what it's fed and being loaded to. It's not that it doesn't display the content, it mucks up the content's 3D coordinates.

Comment: Ah I see, then what is happening is by default your main swf still thinks it is 100x100 and scales itself to match your new dimensions (The scaling is throwing everything else off). You can stop the scaling by adding this in your document class constructor, or in frame 1 if you don't use a document class. stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

Comment: Our minds are working along the same wave length - but that doesn't "do it". In fact, I tried all of the scaling options. I think what I need to do is 1 of 2 things. 1 of which I have been trying with no lock and the other is next on the list.

Comment: the 1st was to try to change the wrapper's size, which is what I've posted here. While I can get the loading swfs dimensions from the loader info, the main document dimensions won't respond to attempts to change them "on the fly" as it were. Now I'm thinking I should try to change the loaded swfs perspectiveProjection properties "back" to their defaults based on the original dimensions because they might be getting changed to the wrapper's when it loads. Not sure, though how to reach into the loaded swf to try that.